# Problem creating a simple NTP server that responds with server's system time

Tags: ntp

I am trying to build a very simple NTP (v3) server that receives NTP requests from IP cameras on the LAN for time synchronization purposes. Cameras are disconnected from the internet so the idea is to use the local PC server as an NTP server for cameras.

I have tried two different approaches.

1. Write simple UDP forwarding to a known NTP server (e.g. time.windows.com). This is working well.
2. Write a simple UDP server listening on port 123 for incoming NTP requests which simply returns server's system time. This is also working quite well for simple undemanding NTP clients (e.g. a physical network router) but it keeps failing for a local HIKVISION camera.

The method: receive a 48 byte buffer. Make sure byte at offset 0 is 0x1B. Turn byte at offset 0 into 0x1C and write current UTC time to last 8 bytes as NTP timestamp. This is working great for most NTP clients but not HIKVISION.

The camera sends this request:

```
1B-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-61-8C-DE-CA-C3-73-89-DC
```

The last 8 bytes are non-zero. If I try to modify my UDP forwarding solution [1] so that the last 8 bytes are zeroed out before forwarding, the camera reports an error. So it turns out these bits are important and probably have some cryptographic significance.

I was digging through RFCs to try to understand this bit but I could not find an explanation. Any sample code I could find ignores this entirely and goes down the simple route.

So the question is... how does one interpret the trailing bytes of the NTP request and how to return a correct NTP response? Some sample code or pointers to resources are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Appendix A starting on page 50 of https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1305.pdf for a description of the NTP packet format.  Those last 8 bytes are supposed to carry the server's response timestamp -- which is exactly why you put a timestamp into those bytes when you build your minimal response packet.

However, based on the fact that this client put a value into those last 8 bytes it looks like it wants to use the mechanism described in Section 5 of the SNTP (Simple NTP) protocol, per https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2030.txt  SNTP uses the same packet format as NTP but uses the fields in a slightly different way.  In SNTP the value the client places into bytes 40 through 47 is the client's current idea of the time.  (In this case it's off by a fair bit, AFAICT that timestamp is sometime around 1951.)

If that's what this client is trying to do then it wants the server to copy those 8 bytes into bytes 24-31 (the Originate Timestamp field), and then write the server's current time into bytes 32-39 (the Receive Timestamp) *and* into bytes 40-47 (the Transmit Timestamp), and send that as the response.  Of course, also continue to change the first byte to 0x1C in the response to indicate that this packet comes from a server.  You should also set the Stratum value in byte 1 to a plausible non-zero value, something like 3 or 4.

Given that the client's clock is off by a long way, it might take several rounds of request/response for it to come into sync.  So don't expect its clock to immediately jump to match the server's clock.  (It might do that, but I wouldn't count on it.)

I don't think you need to complicate your logic by treating this client specially.  You can probably apply exactly this same logic to packets from clients that put zeroes into the last 8 bytes.  It just means you'll be copying zeroes into the Originate Timestamp field when you build responses to those clients.

Comment: Spot on! I did reach the exactly same conclusion a few days ago after installing WireShark and snooping on packets. It became obvious what needs to be done. Still, you provided a super extensive answer that explains it properly. I hated to have to answer my own question. The reason why the camera is doing this is unknown. Your assumption that it takes several rounds to sync the time is wrong. Camera does this only once. And the the time is correct on the camera prior to sending the request so the reason for sending the bogus time seems to be weeding out non-compliant NTP servers.